# Website looks VERY different when uploaded

Tags: html, css

So, my website looks fine when I run it locally on chrome. But when I uploaded it to a webhost, it doesn't look the same at all. The background doesn't show, the text isn't where it should be, and so on. It used to work fine, but now anymore, and I don't know what made it stop working. 
The code is quite sort of "long" so I will upload it to a pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/0N2SMAPg .

How it looks when uploaded: 

[image]

Comment: Did you upload the CSS file in the same relative location?

Comment: check errors in console

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code HERE in a [mcve] - so just enough to show the issue

Comment: It appears that your style sheet (css file) is missing

Comment: Posting code in two different areas doesnt necessarily help clarify this problem. You may want to read the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before you start  asking for help. I'm not sure if webhost supports svg (I don't know a whole lot about SVG) you may want to ask on their forum. I would look for broken links with your css refs also

Comment: Validate your code. Google 'html validator', and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This website doesn't look as on localhost because it doesn't have any styling applied to it. Make sure you include any relevant `.css` or `.js` files as relatives routes and try again. I hope this answers your question. For more, check this out -> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp